# Can you get Apple Logo to glow upon new mail under Power Nap?

Tags: email, notifications, power-nap

Is it possible to be notified of new emails whilst on Power Nap, e. g. via a glowing Apple Logo or some LED (e. g. the LED on the charger)?

Comment: I thought it's good to note that the Apple logo glows because of the LED backlight in your display and not autonomously. So it is only (and always) lit when your display is on.

Comment: Right, one wouldn't like to have the screen lit when the lid is closed, just because there are some notifications waiting. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

Comment: There are some project ideas for about that, e. g. an USB RGB LED and (more for the iPhone) a LED for the headphone jack 
* http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/thingm/blink1-the-usb-rgb-led
* http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/673308573/myled-bringing-external-notifications-to-iphone-an